# How to specify a git tag when in the configuration of the SCM Maven plugin?

Tags: git, maven, maven-3

As a part of my project's configuration, I'm trying to checkout a specific tag out of a GitHub repository. Currently the plugin configuration is as follows:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution><!-- checkout the msgppack-rpc project -->
                    <id>msgpack-rpc-checkout</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>checkout</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <goals>checkout</goals>
                        <connectionUrl>scm:git:https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-rpc.git</connectionUrl>
                        <tag>java-0.6.0</tag>
                        <checkoutDirectory>repoCode/msgpack-rpc</checkoutDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However, the "tag" element seems to be ignored by the Git SCM provider. I've also tried to put the tag directly in the URL, like e.g. so:

`scm:git:https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-rpc.git/refs/tags/java-0.6.0`

Unfortunately, this, and other permutations of this format produce errors. I have no other ideas, and I've failed to find an example for this use case anywhere.

Comment: Are you trying to do the checkout via mvn-scm ? Or for a CI environment?

Comment: Nope, it's one of the build steps of my projects. Don't ask, you'll save your sanity that way ;)...

Comment: Is this really part your build and NOT during a CI ? If yes it sounds really strange. Is the above module part of a multi-module build or is it a stand-alone module?

Comment: Yes, it is a part of the build itself, yes it is atypical, hence my sanity joke. It's a stand-alone module as far as Maven is concerned. Regardless, I think the question asked might be relevant beyond this quite specific case.

Comment: If it is a stand-alone module you can let handle that from outside like the CI and use maven to deploy it into a maven repos and use it as a usual dependency.

Comment: Yes, but it's a workaround. Do you mean to say specifying a tag is impossible in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [checkout goal](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkout-mojo.html) doesn't have the `<tag>` element listed as a parameter.  It looks like you specify the tag info like this:

```
<scmVersionType>tag</scmVersionType>
<scmVersion>java-0.6.0</scmVersion>
```